# Getting back original type of boost variant variable

Tags: c++, c++11

Would you please help me getting back the typename of the original object put into a `boost::variant`?

I have something like this

```
typedef boost::variant<macro,module> ref_var;
```

Is it possible to get back the typename of the original object?  In this case (macro or module)

I was trying to get it using

```
typeid(v).name()
```

but it gives me weird name that is neither macro nor module:

> PN5boost7variantI5macro6moduleNS_6detail7variant5void_ES5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_S5_EE

Would you please help?

Comment: This is the name of type mangled by the compiler. What would you like to achieve? Are `rev_var` and `v` the same thing?

Comment: Hi Rafal, rev_var is the variant type and v is the variable that can either be a macro or a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to get back the textual representation of the types held in a variant, you can roll your own solution:

```
const char* ref_var_typename(const ref_var& v) {
    static const char* types[] = { "macro", "module" };
    return types[v.which()];
}
```

Comment: +1, excellent solution (though you shouldn't take `v` by value, but rather by const-reference).

Comment: Thanks alot Ferruccio and ildjarn, this is a clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

`variant::type()` returns `std::type_info` for the contents of the variant. Just don't use this to choose how to act on the variant — this is best done with visitors.

Comment: Hi Cat, I will not do anything on it accept for getting the type name of the variant back.  Is there a way to do this?  Would you please show me?

Comment: Hi, I use v.type().name() but it gives me error saying v is of non-class type 'ref_var*'

Comment: @BinhVanPham: Did you put something into the `variant`?

Comment: Hi Nicol, I put a macro or a module object into the variant.

Comment: @Binh : You declared a _pointer_ to a `variant<>`, so use `->` instead of `.`. This is very fundamental C++ syntax...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (in the standard) to get the actual C++ typename of *any* type, whether from a `variant` or not. The best you can do is get the `type_info`, but as you see, that is the mangled name, not the actual C++ typename.